# How to make file sync with desired state configuration

Tags: dsc

[SOLVED]
I have a configuration that copies a text file from Pull Server (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter) to the Client (Windows 10), it works as it should be, but i want that two files to be in sync. When i make a change or modification for the text file in Pull Server, i want Client to detect it and apply the differences of the file for itself.

I check file resources attributes to find the appropriate one but i couldn't find. Checksum for modified date also doesn't work.

```
node localhost {

File DirectoryCopy
    {
        Ensure          = 'Present'
        Type            = 'File'
        DestinationPath = 'C:\info.txt'
        SourcePath      = '\\SERVER-dc\Program\info.txt'
        Force           = $true
        Checksum        = "modifiedDate"
        MatchSource     = $true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly but for those who might stick the same problem, i won't delete the question. Replacing checksum line in configuration of the File Resource from "modifiedDate" to "SHA-256" makes two files to remain identical. I am still confused why modified date didn't work.